# Nextjs, Typescript, antd: TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, antd

I'm trying to set up a **nextjs** app with **typescript** and **antdesign**. I prepared a replica of the error I'm getting. ( Link is below ). The problem happens because I changed the default directory of nextjs and the output directory in next.config.js file. I configured ant design and nextje before and it was fine but now that I started the typescript project I faced this issue. Maybe it's not a typescript thing, however!

> TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
> Error: Cannot find module '/MyApp/_next/build-manifest.json'

Replica:

[image: Edit nextjs-ts-antd-saga]

Answer (score 0):

- Remove webpack as a direct `devDependency` in package.json
- Deleted node_modules
- Deleted package.lock.json
- `npm install`